# "Configuration file does not exist", Event ID 274

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

SQL Server 2014 Standard in Server 2012 r2

I installed SQL server 2014 in drive `D:`

I get the following error:

```
Microsoft SSIS Service: 
 Registry setting specifying configuration file does not exist. 
 Attempting to load default config file.
```

Comment: Also have this issue on Server 2016 with SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 0):

Simply add

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\1?0\DTS\Binn\MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml
```

to the default `REG_SZ` value in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\1?0\SSIS\ServiceConfigFile
```

Where the `?` is to be replaced matching your SQL Server version